# Should the [expire] tag be nuked?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Today, I saw a question dealing with sessions timing out too fast that was tagged with [expire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expire). I thought to myself, that sounds pretty generic, as many things can "expire."

Looking through the 109 questions that have been tagged at some point, there is a wide variety of types of questions employing the [expire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expire) tag. I decided perhaps I would put together a tag wiki for it to make it more understandable for what the tag deals with. After much deliberation in my head, I came to the conclusion that this tag is way too ambiguous.

The [expire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expire) tag has been used in at least the following cases:

- Session expiration
- Cache expiration
- Cookie expiration
- Header expiration
- Date/Time expiration
- The [Redis command EXPIRE](http://redis.io/commands/expire)

While the majority of these deal with "data" expiring, they all have much more descriptive tags they could be using (most of which already are), e.g. [session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/session), [caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/caching), [cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cookies), [header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/header), and [datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datetime). The only exception is the Redis EXPIRE command, which is an actual, documented command. However, using the generic [expire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expire) for it is likely to be used incorrectly, which could exactly be what happened here.

Comment: I agree. 109 questions aren't that much.. Should be doable.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Regarding rejected edit: wouldn't adding those tags to the title help if in the future someone will be searching for them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've retagged all 109 [expire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expire) questions. Along came 60-something [expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expired) questions with the same problem - so I took the liberty of removing these tags also.

When I was about to have a feeling of accomplishment I've irresponsibly run a query for the [expires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expires) tag which revealed that there are still 179 questions to go. I'll leave this for tomorrow, in case no one else would like to have some retagging fun.

*Update 1:*

I've removed the [expires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expires) tag from 179 questions, and I was about to have a feeling of accomplishment. Unfortunately, I've irresponsibly run a query for the [expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expiration) tag which revealed that there are still 192 questions to go. I'll leave this for tomorrow, in case no one else would like to have some retagging fun.

*Update 2:*

I've removed the [expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expiration) tag from all questions, and I was about to have a feeling of accomplishment. Unfortunately, I've irresponsibly read [Jonathan Hobbs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/152515/jonathan-hobbs)'s [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217272/231717) to learn that there are also 65 [expiry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expiry) tags to go (now 64 because one was together with [expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expiration) in one question). I'll leave this for tomorrow!

*Update 3:*

I've removed the [expiry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expiry) tag from all but one questions. I was about to have a feeling of accomplishment before editing [this last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337897/whats-the-reason-for-my-asp-net-cache-never-expiring-despite-having-a-sliding), however it was merged and it cannot be edited. As suggested in [this meta thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117789/cant-edit-tags-on-merged-questions) I've flagged it for moderation, and asked for the extermination of the last one of the [expiry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expiry) species.

*Update 4:*

The last [expiry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expiry) tag was removed :-) Mission accomplished!

Comment: Awesome! So I guess you could say these tags are now... _*puts on sunglasses*_ ...expired.

Comment: I've removed some of them (like 4) and I'm already bored :D There's some job with [tag:expiry] also!

Comment: The retagging effort is awesome. Thank you for spending time doing this. However, I have a question, are these tags being blocked from future use? Or will we just get back into an expiration rut in another few months?

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen From what I've read in tag topics here usually there is no need for that - after the tag is unused it disappears, so it won't be available in popup in tag text box. In some cases, when a tag keeps reappearing I think it is possible to blacklist it. I've seen some tags (sorry, can't remember examples) that have wiki saying "Don't use this tag, it's ambiguous". I presume this is the case, then tag's usage is beyond few hundred questions.

Comment: I've added `expire`/`d`/`s` to my list of **170** tags I keep dead daily.  `expiration` and the +100 bounty are for tomorrow...

Answer (score 6):

For the record: a search for [[expir*]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[expir*]) (or a filter of 'expir' on the [tag list](https://stackoverflow.com/tags)) returns the following tags:

[expiry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expiry) × 65

[expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expiration) × 188

and the ones already taken care of by BartoszKP: [expire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expire) [expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expired) [expires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expires) × 0